# ruby on rails multiply set select function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have currently the following select box in my form:

```
%h1 Create New Movie

= form_tag movies_path do

  = label :movie, :title, 'Title'
  = text_field :movie, 'title'
  = label :movie,:description,'Description'
  = text_field :movie,'description'


  = label :movie, :rating, 'Rating'
  = select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17','SSS'],:multiple => true

  = label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On'
  = date_select :movie, :release_date

  = submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```

I want to add the  multiple selections for this select box and I add the multiply=> true after the select function but still can only choose one rating.

Comment: did you try `select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17','SSS'], multiple: true` ?

Comment: Docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: yes,  I already try this method but dosen't  work

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work"? A multi-select box doesn't show up in the view? You're not getting an array in your controller? Your model isn't set up to handle an array of ratings?

Comment: sorry for confusion. There was select box here before. select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17','SSS']I added the multiple:true but nothing changed.

Comment: @ShaoboWang please update question with code, which isn't work, i.e. with multiple select

Comment: I already updated. Thanks